# Client side validation errors not include in generated string from "Render a view as a string" method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I am using string generated by the razor version of the method from:

[Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string/2759898#2759898)

But it does not include errors added to `ModelState` on the server side.

When I checked it:

Variable `viewContext` is correct - its property `ViewData.ModelState` contains errors, but after:

`viewResult.View.Render( viewContext, sw );`
the string in `sw` variable contains html without error messages etc ( I mean it is html which should be generated for ModelState without errors).

Is there a way to correct it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.

The method [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string/2759898#2759898) works correctly.

The reason `ViewModel` errors where not shown is typo in the field name to which error should be joined.